# Internet connection & IIS stopped on windows xp after VMware server 2 installation

Tags: windows-xp, vmware-server

I'm running a local network. My IP ranges from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.15. All IP are static ones. And my router's IP is 192.168.1.1 and I provide it as default gateway and preferred DNS server on client machines.

Everything worked fine on this scenario. I could use internet and reach services on other machines.
BUT I have installed VMware server 2 on the windows XP to host windows 2003 Virtual Machine (VM).
I set the following configuration:

```
Windows XP's => 192.168.1.11. 
Windows 2003 => 192.168.1.12. (virtual machine)
```

This approach worked just fine as it used to work with Microsoft Virtual PC. I can access mysql & IIS websites on the windows 2003 virtual machine.

BUT two things doesn't work anymore on the Windows XP:

1. internet connection - but I can see the MAC address on the wireless router
2. IIS -  Ping on 127.0.0.1 it's ok as I can hit localhost:8222 nor localhost

Does anyone knows how to fix any of this? (at least the internet connection)

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the virtual network adapters VMWare Server installs automatically on your host, and see if things get better; they're called "VMware Network Adapter VMnetX".

Answer (score 0):

I dont remember the specifics...  but i think its related the the type of vNIC you are presenting to the Server.  Have you tried the other options undrer the VM Server for that hosts NIC?